# Caret or down arrow not appearing in select tag

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to put a caret or a down-arrow on `select` in a form. I have tried a lot but it doesn't appears in the select box. Can someone help?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="control-label col-sm-3" id="label_form">Category</label>
   <div class="col-sm-4 ">
     <select class="form-control input-lg" name="category" id="category">
        <option>ONE</option>
        <option>TWO</option>
     </select>
   </div>
 </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.form-control{
     padding:9px 18px 9px 12px !important;
     margin: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
     border-radius:4px;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px #fff inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px #fff inset;
     box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px #fff inset;
     background: #f8f8f8;
     color:#888;
     border-color: #66afe9;
     outline:none;
     display: inline-block;
     -webkit-appearance:none;
     -moz-appearance:none;
     appearance:none;
     cursor:pointer;
     color: #555;
     font-size: 14px;
     height: 40px !important;
     display: block;
}
```

**Current view:**

[image: Current view of select tag]

**Expected view:**

[image: Expected view of select tag]

Comment: Remove `appearance` properties from your styles. Check [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Muhammad_Usman/7tsds32d/).

Comment: I made that with the appearance, but I don't like the result with the default down-arrow. I want to make it with better arrow. For example like the arrow of the image that I gave. Do you have anything to suggest me?

Comment: I tried to put the caret class with a spam tag before the select tag, after the select tag and nowhere appeared. I don't know what to do.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman can you help me?

Comment: Check this [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-a-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript) for detailed answer.

Comment: Thanks @MuhammadUsman for the help. I have one more thing to handle. When the select opens I want the border and the hole box below, be the same with the select. I have an image, but I don't understrand how to upload it from here.

Comment: In this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6g5ezoro/) they are having same width.

Comment: Style and design I want. Not width. But thanks @MuhammadUsman